# Update UI from async task lambda in WinRT

Tags: c++, wpf, asynchronous, windows-runtime, c++-cx

I am writing a small WinRT program to async create a folder and a file. The simplified code is like below:

```
auto createFolderOp = ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder->CreateFolderAsync(L"DummyFolder", CreationCollisionOption::OpenIfExists);

create_task(createFolderOp).then([](task<StorageFolder ^> folder)
{
    StorageFolder ^tempFolder;

    tempFolder = uploadFolder.get();

    return tempFolder->CreateFileAsync(L"DummyFile.txt", CreationCollisionOption::ReplaceExisting);

}).then([] (task<StorageFile ^> dummyFile)
{
    StorageFile ^file;

    file = dummyFile.get();

    FileIO::WriteTextAsync(file, L"Dummy Content");
});
```

During the execution of this code, I want to update my UI on each step. For example I have a textblock and in each step I want to update it to show different text, such as:

```
Create Folder Succeed...
Create File Succeed...
Write File Succeed...
```

etc.

How can I access to the UI element from Async task? What is the best practice of doing this?

Comment: `What is the best practice of doing this?` - read about [Data Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just capture the UI element variable and update it in the lambda body.

Comment: Thought I would expand on this a little bit.  in your task continuation you can capture variables by object or by pointer.  You can always just pass `this` to your continuation via `.then([this] (...)`.  I have noticed that intellisense doesn't always pick up on the UI Elements but if you type the name out and follow it with `->` and it will usually catch on.

side note:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15119897/exception-handling-winrt-c-concurrency-async-tasks?rq=1  <- info about handling errors in tasks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to update the UI from the UI thread. I wrote a post a while ago about getting to the UI thread from different types of Windows Phone apps, it should be applicable to Windows RT Apps as well: http://robwirving.com/2013/07/17/guide-to-getting-to-the-ui-thread-for-any-type-of-windows-phone-8-app/

If you're using Windows Xaml, you should be able to get the Dispatcher from the CoreWindow object and run a lambda using the dispatcher's [RunAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runasync.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp) method.

If you're trying to get to the UI thread from a WinRT component, well that's a bit more difficult, but I have a method here: http://robwirving.com/2014/06/02/getting-to-the-ui-thread-from-a-windows-phone-winrt-component/