# concurrency and exception handling

Tags: concurrency, exception, uwp, c++-cli

So I have the following code:

```
        StorageFolder^ storageFolder = ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder;

        concurrency::create_task(storageFolder->GetFileAsync(txtfile)).then([](StorageFile^ sampleFile)
        {

            concurrency::create_task(FileIO::AppendTextAsync(sampleFile, New_Program_Data)).then([]() {

            });

        });
```

Which I use to open a text file and append some data to the end. How can I add exception handling in the event that the file is missing or corrupt or can't be opened?

I've tried various **try and catch** statements inside and outside the tasks, but nothing seems to work when debugging. The application will break and show an unhandled exception error.

Comment: You need to use `task<StorageFile^>`s as arguments of countinuation function to get exceptions, if you use the `StorageFile^` you'll not be able to get the exceptions. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997692.aspx and https://stackoverflow.com/a/15123425/8918119

Answer (score 0):

As I remember you're able to catch exceptions like this:

```
concurrency::create_task(storageFolder->GetFileAsync(txtfile))
.then([](StorageFile^ sampleFile)
{
    // Do whatever you want when successful.
})
.then([] (task<void> previousTask)
{
    // Catch any exceptions of your previous task here.

    try
    {
        // Get the result of the previous task.
        // This also results in exceptions getting thrown.
        previousTask.get();
    }
    catch(Exception^ ex)
    { }
});
```