# UWP: Catch error when reading file

Tags: file, error-handling, uwp, c++-cx

I have successfully been able to open and read files in a `UWP` `C++` app using the following code:

```
FileOpenPicker^ openPicker = ref new FileOpenPicker();
openPicker->SuggestedStartLocation= PickerLocationId::DocumentsLibrary;
openPicker->FileTypeFilter->Append(".txt");


create_task(openPicker->PickSingleFileAsync()).then([this](StorageFile^ file)
{
    if (file)
    {
        create_task(FileIO::ReadTextAsync(file)).then([this](Platform::String^ text) {

            MessageDialog^ msg = ref new MessageDialog(text);
            msg->ShowAsync();

        });
    }
    else
    {
        MessageDialog^ msg = ref new MessageDialog("Operation cancelled.");
        msg->ShowAsync();
    }
});
```

However, if the file content is non-textual e.g. binary, the app crashes. How do I implement error handling? I have tried using `try...catch` unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem by referring to

- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5b84396b-f071-4c29-ab11-78757d0206f1/uwp-try-catch-block-doesnt-work-in-my-uwp?forum=wpdevelop
- [Exception handling, WinRT C++ concurrency async tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15119897/exception-handling-winrt-c-concurrency-async-tasks)

The `try...catch` should be placed inside the asynchronous task. I was putting it outside. For this, the parameters of `create_task()` should be changed:

```
FileOpenPicker^ openPicker = ref new FileOpenPicker();
openPicker->SuggestedStartLocation= PickerLocationId::DocumentsLibrary;
openPicker->FileTypeFilter->Append(".txt");


create_task(openPicker->PickSingleFileAsync()).then([this](StorageFile^ file)
{
    if (file)
    {
            create_task(FileIO::ReadTextAsync(file)).then([this](task<String^> currentTask) {

                try {
                    String ^text = currentTask.get();
                    MessageDialog^ msg = ref new MessageDialog(text);
                    msg->ShowAsync();
                }
                catch (...) {
                    MessageDialog^ msg = ref new MessageDialog("Exception handled.");
                    msg->ShowAsync();
                }
            });

    }
    else
    {
        MessageDialog^ msg = ref new MessageDialog("Operation cancelled.");
        msg->ShowAsync();
    }
});
```

When this code is run inside Visual Studio, it will still break showing some hexadecimal symbols when the error occurs. Simply click on `Continue` or `F5` to get the `Exception handled.` error message.