# Unknown C++ exception on operator new under MSVC

Tags: c++, memory, visual-c++, pinvoke, new-operator

I'm facing an unknown exception thrown after I call the `new` operator.

The `new` operator is called after a long processing time (10h) to store output results. **This code is implemented in a DLL that is loaded from a C# application running in .Net 4.5.**

I created a MWE with the code below put into a for loop, but it throws an `std::bad_alloc` as expected, while the real code throws unknown exception and falls to the `catch(...)` statement.

Note that I am using Visual Studio 2013.

This is the code:

```
try {

  char* output = new char[50000000];

} catch (const std::bad_alloc&) {
  // Doesn't happen
  printf("Bad Alloc\n");
} catch (const std::exception&) {
  // Doesn't happen
  printf("Standard Exception\n");
} catch (...) {
  // Code falls here
  printf("Unknown Exception\n");
}
```

If no one has a solution for this, can you at least please give ideas for debugging it? I've thought about using Windows API calls to check memory state before calling the `new` operator, but I need more ideas.

What are all types of exceptions MSVC can throw upon operator `new` and what can I do to retrieve information from those?

Comment: Can you post the whole code?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. If the use of `new` operator fails in the MWE, why would you expect for it to work after 10 hours of processing time ?

Comment: @Norgannon the code fails in MWE with std::bad_alloc, but in runtime it fails with unknown exception

Comment: I'd probably try with a memory sanitiser and an external memory analyser. If they don't throw anything up then you may be looking at some UB (though i'd say this is unlikely if nothing else weird has happened over 10 hrs).

Comment: @kiner_shah I can't, sorry

Comment: Do you have any idea of what kind of exception does it throw? maybe you can try using RTTI to print the actual exception type. Or just run it in a debugger and break at the catch.

Comment: When I tried this in VS 21013 I also got a bad_alloc. I am not sure how to reproduce.

Comment: @bracco23 how do you use RTTI for that? Could you perhaps provide an example?

Comment: @manatttta you can use `typeid(exception).name() ` to print the name of the class. you can find more details [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid)

Comment: @bracco23 yes but the code is falling to the `catch(...)` case so how can I use `typeid` there?

Comment: Do you have SEH enabled?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414027/visual-c-unmanaged-code-use-eha-or-ehsc-for-c-exceptions also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/eh-exception-handling-model?view=vs-2017

Comment: It appears some CLR options enable SEH. Are you using clr?

Comment: @drescherjm not using CLR!

Comment: @drescherjm actually this is implemented on a DLL that is loaded from a C# application. Does this mean it has CLR? Or that it runs in a managed environment?

Comment: Is it a C++/CLI DLL (using normal reference from C#) or a plain C++ DLL (using P/Invoke from C#)? Also, is this 32-bit or 64-bit code? Anyway, a `catch(...)` reacting to `new` most likely means corrupted heap, i.e. the real problem is probably a buffer overflow somewhere else.

Comment: @SebastianRedl yes I agree this is probably corrupted heap. This is 32bit, I think it uses PInvoke